# Have trouble creating an hello-world module in drupal 5

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-5

Here're the steps I did to create an mudule:

1. create a directory `groups` under `sites/all/modules`
2. in the above directory `groups`, create two files `groups.module` and `groups.info`

The content of `groups.info`:

```
; $Id: groups.info,v 1.3 2006/11/21 20:55:36 dries Exp $
name = groups
description = Test Groups Listings.
package = "test groups"

version = "5.10"
project = "ed_groups"
datestamp = "1218672307"
```

The content of `groups.module`:

```
<?php
function groups_menu($may_cache)
{
    $items = array();
    $items[] = array(
        'path' => 'test_menu',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'callback' => 'groups_list',
        'title' => t('All Group Listing')
    );
}

function groups_list()
{
    return 'helloworld';
}
```

I got an oops(404) page when visiting `site.com/test_menu`

Can you spot what's wrong above?

Comment: Also, what's an error? I guess drupal tells you something (or just doesn't show the module)?

Comment: I got a oops page when visiting `site.com/test_menu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you don't return $items in your `hook_menu`.

It should be:

```
function groups_menu($may_cache) {
    $items = array();
    $items[] = array(
        'path' => 'test_menu',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'callback' => 'groups_list',
        'title' => t('All Group Listing')
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Remember to clear the cache after you do this, as Drupal caches the menu system.

Comment: Does **drupal** require some kind of configuration to enable before a newly created module can take affect?

Comment: You need to enable the module, before it will do anything.